# d3.geo.albersUsa() not function

Tags: d3.js, dc.js

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Store Location</title>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/queue.v1.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        * {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        .boundary {
            fill: none;
            stroke: #dfdfdf;
            stroke-linejoin: round;
        }
        #map {
            text-align: center;
        }
        circle {
            fill: blue;
            opacity:.9;
        }
        text{
            font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
            font-weight: 300;
            font-size: 12px;
            z-index: 900;
        }
        #tooltip {
            position: absolute;
            width: 200px;
            height: auto;
            padding: 10px;
            background-color: #ff9436;
            -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
            -moz-border-radius: 10px;
            border-radius: 10px;
            -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
            -moz-box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
            box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
            pointer-events: none;
        }
        #tooltip.hidden {
            display: none;
        }
        #tooltip p {
            margin: 0;
            font-family: sans-serif;
            font-size: 16px;
            line-height: 20px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="tooltip" >
    <p><strong>Store name and address:</strong></p>
    <p><span id="value"></span></p>
    <svg id="spendChart"></svg>
</div>
<div id="map"></div>
<script>
    var height = 600;
    var width = 900, centered;
    

    var projection = d3.geo.albersUsa()
            .scale(1200)
            .translate([width/2, height/2]);


            console.log("working..!!!")


    var path = d3.geo.path().projection(projection);

    var svg = d3.select("#map")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height);

    var map = svg.append("g")
                 .attr("class", "boundary");

    var usa, usData, spendData, locationData;

    var monthParser = d3.time.format("%b");

    d3.select("#tooltip").classed("hidden", true);

    queue()
         .defer(d3.json, 'us.json')
         .defer(d3.json, 'newstorelocations.json')
         .defer(d3.json, 'newstorespend.json')
         .await(ready);

    function onHover(location) {
        var pos = projection([location.lon, location.lat]),
            html = location.name + 
                   "<br />located at: <br />" + 
                   location.AddressLine1 + 
                   ",<br />" + 
                   location.City + 
                   "<br />" + 
                   location.StateCode;

        d3.select("#value").html(html);
        d3.select("#tooltip").attr("left", pos[0] + "px").attr("top", pos[1] + "px").classed("hidden", false);
        d3.select(this).style("fill", "red");

        var locationSpendData = spendData.filter(function(d) { return d.StoreDescription == location.StoreDescription; });

        locationSpendData.forEach(function(d) {
            d.month = monthParser.parse(d.MonthName);
        });

        var chartHeight = 150, chartWidth = 200,
            x = d3.time.scale().domain(d3.extent(locationSpendData, function(d) { return d.month; }))
                               .range([0, chartWidth]),
            y = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, d3.max(locationSpendData, function(d) { return d.TotalSpend; })])
                                 .range([chartHeight, 0]);

        chart = d3.select("svg#spendChart").attr("height", chartHeight)
                                           .attr("width", chartWidth);

        chart.selectAll("rect.bar")
             .data(locationSpendData)
           .enter().append("rect")
             .attr("class", "bar")
             .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.month); })
             .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.TotalSpend); })
             .attr("width", chartWidth / locationSpendData.length)
             .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.TotalSpend); });

    }

    function offHover() {
        d3.select(this).style("fill", "blue");
        d3.select("#spendChart").html("");
        d3.select("#tooltip").classed("hidden", true);
    }

    function ready(error, us, locations, spend) {
        usData = us;
        locationData = locations;
        spendData = spend;

        usa = map.selectAll('path')
                .data(topojson.feature(usData, usData.objects.states).features);

        usa.enter()
                .append('path')
                .attr('d', path)
                .attr('fill', 'gray');

        svg.selectAll('circle')
                .data(locationData)
                .enter()
                .append('circle')
                .attr('cx', function(d) {return projection([d.lon, d.lat])[0]})
                .attr('cy', function(d) {return projection([d.lon, d.lat])[1]})
                .attr('r', 4)
                .on("mouseover", onHover)
                .on("mouseout", offHover);
    };
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: error in browser console..]

i am creating USA  map and location of store on it...
but i getting an error as shown in the image that 
 i added to us.json and to another .json file for location ...
but no output is getting shown in browser.
i am getting error like this.. .
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'objects' of undefined

Comment: The first error you got indicates that the file `us.json` wasn't loaded due to cross-origins request policy. That's likely means `ready()` was called with an error and `us` undefined.

Comment: Looks like a reasonable question to me; I don't understand the close vote. I guess I'm confused why the error in the title is different from the error shown in the screenshot.

Comment: sorry ...but how to solve Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'path' of undefined error ..i got this error

Comment: and how to load  us.json file to solve 1 error

Comment: Thing is, you have to show your current code in order for people to help you. You can't be getting that error on `d3.geo.path` if it got past `d3.geo.albersUsa` because those indicate that `d3.geo` is undefined somehow.

Comment: Search around for "cross origin d3" and you'll be able to solve the us.json error. Basically you need to run a local web server in order to load data correctly - browsers don't let you work with data over `file://` for security reasons. It's easy, e.g. you could use `python3 -m http.server` or node's [http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server)